# Building MongoDB with SSL RedHat fails: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: mongodb, ssl, scons

Trying to build MongoDB with SSL on RHEL 6.4, I get the error

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Tried running the failed line with -v for g++ verbosity, in order to get some usefule information, but got no further information. All I get is:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix

gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) 

COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/

LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'build/linux2/ssl/mongo/mongotop' '-fPIC' '-pthread' '-rdynamic' '-L/usr/lib64' '-L/lib64' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
...
...
build/linux2/ssl/third_party/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/src/singledocparser.o build/linux2/ssl/third_party/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/src/stream.o build/linux2/ssl/third_party/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/src/tag.o --end-group -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

(This one last "line" fills up ~2 screens, so I omitted most of it, leaving the beginning and end of it.

Next line is just the error: `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`. Nothing more.

Any idea how to figure out this error?

Comment: It is not possible to tell what is going wrong without the output of `ld` that you omitted. Run `make` again (after the first error) and edit your question to add the output of `ld` (at least the significant parts of it). I would bet on a missing -devel package, but no way to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The error is thrown from a `g++` line. What does `make` have to do with it? (Running `scons` again now to get the error, but It'll take ~30 min)

Comment: Thanks, @Pierre, I went by your hunch, and it was boost-devel that was missing.

Comment: OK if you want your question here to be helpful, please add an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures out package boost-devel was missing.